# Who is this hero?

Tags: castle-clash

Today when playing in the Lost Battlefield, I noticed a weird hero I never saw before: (left most)

[image]

Who is this hero? I went over to the [full heros list in the wiki site](http://castle-clash.wikia.com/wiki/Heroes), and found no hero looking like that.

(On a side note, this hero is super powerful)

Comment: There are no new heroes lately, no skins or anything of the sort?

Comment: @n_palum thanks, but the newest hero is Mechtessa, which does appear in the wiki. I never installed any skins, so don't think it's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a skin for Cupid, the "Robin Hood" skin. Source: [Castle Crash Official Instagram account](http://pikore.co/media.php?id=1557072686956684557_1179497489)

Comment: I thought it looked like Cupid I just didn't know about skins

Comment: @n_palum heh, me too! Thought it is something you install locally. Lol

Comment: Also on twitter: https://twitter.com/CastleClashIGG/status/885160981105487873.